# Is the preposition repeated when there are two prepositional complements?

Tags: prepositions

Is the preposition repeated when there are two prepositional complements in Italian?

Example

- L'inglese è utile nella diplomazia e il turismo.
- L'inglese è utile nella diplomazia e nel turismo.

Answer (score 2):

You have to repeat the preposition if it is articulated as in your exemple:

- L'inglese è utile nella diplomazia e nel turismo.

The repetition is optional if the preposition is simple:

- L'inglese è parlato in Inghilterra e Scozia
- L'inglese è parlato in Inghilterra e in Scozia

Omitting the repetition is more common in this case ([exemple](https://www.leggo.it/italia/cronache/il_governatore_abruzzo_anticipa_governo_zona_arancione_basilicata_umbria_liguria_toscana-5575697.html)), but repeating it, you put a stronger separation between the elements of the list, sometime giving a different nuance of meaning or helping avoiding ambiguities

- L'inglese non è parlato nelle province di Pesaro e Urbino e di Monza e Brianza

Technically speaking, I think that if you don't repeat the preposition it counts as a single complement (not sure though, please correct me if I'm wrong), but I guess it was not the goal of the question.

Comment: From the examples, I assume that "if the preposition is simple" means "if the preposition is not accompanied by an article"?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista:     From [Treccani dictionary](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/preposizione/): "Si dicono preposizioni articolate le parole risultanti dalla fusione di una preposizione semplice (...) con le forme dell’articolo determinativo".